# How to use matplotlib to draw 3D barplot with specific color according to the bar height

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d

[image]

Hey guys, I am using matplotlib to draw 3D barplot. I wonder whether it is possible to give each bar (total 9) a different color according to their value (dz) and also show the corresponding level in this figure.

Many thanks in advance!!!

My code is below:

```
fig_stat=plt.figure(dpi=100)
ax_stat = fig_stat.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xpos = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5]
ypos = [1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5]
# initial z position (x-y plane), np.zeros(x), x
zpos = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
# x is the number of points you need

dx = np.ones(9)
dy = np.ones(9)
# dz = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9]  # signal intensity
dz = col_stat.iloc[:, -2]
ax_stat.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax_stat.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax_stat.set_zlabel('Signal Intensity')
ax_stat.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='#00ceaa')
plt.title("Position_{}".format(L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bar3d` method allows to enter as color an array of the same length as the data arrays. Therefore, a colormap can be used to get the colors corresponding to each `dz`:

```
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
cmap = cm.get_cmap('plasma')
norm = Normalize(vmin=min(dz), vmax=max(dz))
colors = cmap(norm(dz))
```

And use this `colors` as input in the bar3d color parameter instead of `'#00ceaa'`. Afterwards, the colorbar can be shown using this piece of code:

```
sc = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
sc.set_array([])
plt.colorbar(sc)
```

Which will generate a plot looking like this:

[image: bar cmap]

Comment: Hey, thank you for you kind help. However, after I add your code, it has sth wrong.

Comment: Hey, thank you for you kind help. However, after I add your code, it has sth wrong with "Unknown projection '3d". Could you tell me where to add your code to mine at your convenience? My email is tracygao911@gmail.com

Thanks.

Comment: I figured out the reason, I missed the package: from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

Comment: Yes, it is still necessary. I only included the code that had to be added, and importing Axes3D must be in your original code. I hope everything is clear and I have not missed anything from the question